# What does "~B" represent in a vi file?

Tags: vi

In vi, I have a text file which shows several blue ~B characters. I've spent a few hours trying to find any references to what ~B represents in a vi file but have not found anything.

I know that a ^ preceding a letter represents a control character. ^H represents the hex byte 0x08 for Backspace. I'm familiar with using Ctrl V to enter or search for various control characters but I have no idea what the ~B represents or how to design a search and replace command to delete them.

To delete control characters from the entire file, I would use, for example, :%s/^H//g, using Ctrl V then hitting the backspace key to get the 0x08 byte. Doing that for ~B doesn't work.

Comment: SUGGESTION: Look at the file in a hex editor.  Find the place where "~B" appears in the editor, and look at the ASCII (?) code for the character in that position.  Please post back what you find - I'm curious :)

Comment: Thanks for the hexdump suggestion. I figured it out. The file is a very large list of words including lots from foreign languages. In my bash shell I had exported LC_ALL=C. It turns out with that setting the ~B in vi is 0x82, ~C=0x83, ~H=0x88 and so on. Then I've seen things like this <a4><f5> which turns out to be 0xa4 0xf5. 

In other words, they are accented characters from foreign alphabets like é, ê, ï. Without LC_ALL=C vi shows those bytes as their hex code in angle brackets like <82>, <83> with a few exceptions like ¼ which is 0xac.

Comment: After entering `export LC_ALL=C`, I see the blue `~B` and so on (a text generated from 0x00 to 0xff), but I can't see `<a4>` or `<f5>`.  I see ¤ for 0ax4 and õ for 0xf5 instead